# Aptana fails at start up with unclear error log

Tags: java, eclipse

I get "An error has occurred" starting Aptana 3, pointing me at the log file. This gives:

> !SESSION 2020-10-24 14:19:20.685
> ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=11.0.8 java.vendor=Ubuntu
> BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
> Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-10-24 14:19:22.381 !MESSAGE
> Application error !STACK 1 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
> at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:126)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472) Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
> ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by
> org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418     at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 25 more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-10-24 14:19:22.386
> !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> javax/annotation/PreDestroy   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
> at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)    at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot
> be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418     at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 21 more

Can anyone please suggest where I go from here?

Comment: The version of Eclipse is too old to run with Java 11. Either use a newer version or go back to Java 8

Comment: Oh, I know I had to install Java 8 when I installed this version of Aptana. How do I move back to Java 8? Reinstall it?

Comment: I've now changed the default back to Java 8 and Aptana works as it should. Thank you to everyone for their help.